# Probability question involving conditional probability

Tags: probability

A medical patient is diagnosed with a condition that is fatal $60$% of the time. One possible treatment involves a surgical procedure. Research has shown that 40% of survivors had surgery and 10% of non-survivors had surgery. What is the probability of the patient surviving the condition if they have surgery?

So I say:

$P(L) = live$

$P(D) = die$

$P(S) = surgery$

$P(N) = no surgery$

We want:

$P(L \mid S) = \frac{P(L \cap S)}{P(S)}$

I'm lost as to how we can write in terms of probability "40% of survivors had surgery and 10% of non-survivors had surgery"

I'm hitting a wall which intuitively should be easy to pass but I can't seem to get my head around the problem.

Anyone know how to approach this with a better intuition than me for probability?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You write that $P(S|L)=0.4$ (the probability that the person had surgery given that they lived is 0.4) and $P(S|D)=0.1$ (the probability that the person had surgery given that they died is 0.1).
$$
P(L\cap S)=P(L|S)\times P(S)=P(S|L)\times P(L)
$$
Thus
$$
P(L|S)=P(S|L)\times{P(L)\over P(S)}
$$
Now
$$
\begin{align}
P(S)&=P(S|L)P(L)+P(S|D)P(D)\\
&=0.4\times 0.4+0.1\times0.6\\
&=0.22
\end{align}
$$
Can you finish it?

Comment: @JohnDoe What is not clear in the above equation? It gives P(S) in terms of P(D).

Comment: @JohnDoe Please don't edit the comments like that, just ask another question. P(D) is the probability of dying which is 0.6 because 60% of patients die. $P(L)$ is $1-P(D)$

Comment: I would like to know how you got P(S) in terms of P(D). It seems you jumped to that equation

Comment: $P(S)=P(S\cap L)+P(S\cap D)$. You're not making enough effort here.

Comment: Of course. That was the one step I had left out. I had reached that point quite easily and seemed to have forgotten that simple fact